# UICollectionView - Last Row Not Showing

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have created a `UICollectionView` programmatically that will be displayed within a larger `UIView`.  I've setup the delegate and datasource correctly, and it renders with no problem.  However, when I increase the number of cells in the view to the point that scrolling is necessary to see the last row, I find that the `UICollectionView` is not able to scroll to the bottom.  The last row is visible on the bounce, but is cut off when the bounce ends.  Only about 10 pixels of a 75x75 pixel cell are visible, and there is no way past this.

I've tried increasing the content size, but that seems to have no affect.  Is there something else I need to be doing to get the last row to display properly?

**UPDATE**:  Perhaps a bit more details is in order...

My view setup looks like this:  I have a paging-enabled UIScrollView that acts as my top-level UIView.  Within this, I have created a series of UICollectionView objects.  My UIScrollView is designed to scroll horizontally, while the UICollectionViews scroll vertically.  I am accomplishing this using the [RGMPagingScrollView library](https://github.com/rydermackay/RGMPagingScrollView) so I can benefit from reusable collection views to conserve memory.

As recommended, I took a look at implementing auto layout programmatically, but I am unclear as to exactly what to do.  I've tried a couple different routes, but I end up with layout constraint errors.  I also looked at the bounds and frame sizes for my collection views, and they appear to be correct.  They end up being {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}, which I would expect for a full-screen collection view on my device.

I also took a look to see what the superview bounds/frame would be, but found that the superview for my UICollectionView was nil, which I did not expect since it is embedded within a UIScrollView.  At this point, I'm at a loss as to what could be going on here.  I've modified both the bounds and frame (shrinking the height by up to 200 px), thinking that might make a difference, but the behavior is the same.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I think you set the return value wrong in - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: Odrakir's answer is correct; the `frame` of your UICollectionView is set improperly. If you show us how you're configuring your layout we can show you what's incorrect about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You UICollectionView is probably going off screen. You can try autolayout to fix its size to its superview's size. You can also do it with autoresizing masks or overriding viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: Looks like it was a bug in the library I was using.  It was not sizing the subviews properly, so they were rendering offscreen.  I've corrected it.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks @Odrakir you saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

This issue may also occur if minimumLineSpacing is being set for horizontal scrolling UICollectionViewFlowLayout.
Removing this worked for me.